# What functions/classes do I have to export from DLLs?

Tags: c++, dllexport

Not a great title, so I will explain it here.

I know I have to export any function or class a client application directly calls. For simplicity, I will refer to them as 'API functions/classes'.

My questions are (They will be further explained by the code blocks below):

1. Do I need to export any function that an API function calls?
2. Do I need to export any class that an API class derives from?

```cpp
// this function will never be called directly by the client application.
// it should be included by a cpp file and not exposed to a public header file
// do I need to export it?
void anotherFunction();

// this function WILL be called directly by the client application. 
// it should be declared in a public header file, and defined in a cpp file.
__declspec(dllexport) void APIFunction()
{
    anotherFunction();
}
```

```cpp
// this class will NOT be directly used by a client application
// the declaration will be included in a public header file
// and the definition will be in a cpp file
// do I need to export this class?
class BaseClass {};

// this class will be directly used by a client application
// it should be declared in a public header file, and defined in a cpp file 
class __declspec(dllexport) APIClass : public BaseClass {};
```

Answer (score 3):

If external code is supposed to be able to use a class or function (in any way), then it needs to be exported. If not, then it doesn't need to. Simple as that.

A simple test is; does the external code link and run successfully? If yes, then you've exported what you need (at least). Otherwise, if you get linker errors (or run time linker errors), then you know that you need to export what the (dynamic) linker is complaining about.